# Attempting to get the average from numbers in a dictionary

Tags: function, average

I want to use the average function to get an *avg* using values in a dictionary. I am getting *unexpected EOF* while parsing. I suspect I have the formatting of my function all wrong.

```
def get_average(numbers):
    return(numbers(sum/(len))
```

Answer (score 0):

I completely rewrite your code. Here is how I compute the average of the dictionary members.

```
def get_average(numbers):
    val = 0
    for v in numbers.values():
        val += v
    avg = val / len(numbers)
    return avg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = {
        'one': 1,
        'two': 2
    }

    print(get_average(numbers)) # 1.5
```